# How to get Indices from pattern matching?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
https://mywebsite/products?category_ids=1&category_ids=3&category_ids=4&category_ids=11&category_ids=10048&category_ids=10785
```

This is my url with searching patterns. Now I want to filter and get the ids of `category_ids`

Output should be:

```
[1, 3, 4, 11, 10048, 10785]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a one-liner:

```js
console.log(new URL('https://mywebsite/products?category_ids=1&category_ids=3&category_ids=4&category_ids=11&category_ids=10048&category_ids=10785').searchParams.getAll('category_ids').map(Number));
```

References:

- [`URL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL)
- [`URL.searchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/searchParams)
- [`URLSearchParams.getAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/getAll)
- [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

Comment: All are coming `NaN`

Answer (score 2):

You can easily achieve the result using regex as

**1)**

```js
const url =
  "https://mywebsite/products?category_ids=1&category_ids=3&category_ids=4&category_ids=11&category_ids=10048&category_ids=10785";

const result = url
  .split("?")[1]
  .match(/(?<==)\d+/g)
  .map(Number);
console.log(result);
```

**2)**

```js
const url =
  "https://mywebsite/products?category_ids=1&category_ids=3&category_ids=4&category_ids=11&category_ids=10048&category_ids=10785";

const result = url
  .split("?")[1]
  .match(/=\d+/g)
  .map((s) => +s.slice(1));
console.log(result);
```